# Ada - "type has no constraint" error when instantiating record

Tags: ada

I've got some Ada code that looks like this:

```
type NODE;
type NODE_PTR is access NODE;
type PRINT_PTR is access procedure(X: NODE_PTR);
type NODE is
record
             parent : NODE_PTR;
             left : NODE_PTR;
             right : NODE_PTR;
             id : INTEGER;
             visit : PRINT_PTR;
end record;

procedure PRINT(X : NODE_PTR) is
...
end PRINT;
```

Later in my code I try to instantiate NODEs like this:

```
root : NODE_PTR;
id_value : INTEGER;
...
root := new NODE(NULL, NULL, NULL, id_value, PRINT'access);
...
```

and this:

```
ret_ptr : NODE_PTR;
id_value : INTEGER;
...
ret_ptr := new NODE(parent, NULL, NULL, id_value, PRINT'access);
```

When trying to "gnatmake" this code the compiler complains about both assign-statements saying: "invalid constraint: type has no discriminant".
What's wrong? As far as I can tell I'm not defining any discriminants in NODE and I'm not trying to assign any discriminants in those new NODE - calls.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When allocating access types with an initial value, you need a ' like this:

```
root := new NODE'(NULL, NULL, NULL, id_value, PRINT);
```

Comment: Right. With the `'`, `NODE'(...)` is a qualified expression. Without it, `NODE(...)` is a subtype -- or it would be if `NODE` had the appropriate discriminants.